# Excel range.Find returning null C#

Tags: c#, excel

Ok, so here is the scoop. I have an excel sheet that holds quote numbers for clients all stored in the C column in my worksheet. I have it so when selected the program will take the quote number from the datagridview and search for it in excel. Here is the code :

```
                public static string pQuoteHolder;  


                file = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "__Quote_Tracker.xlsm");
                Excel.Application xlapp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(file);
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
                Excel.Range currentFind = null;
                Excel.Range firstFind = null;
                Excel.Range range;
                Excel.Range clients = xlapp.get_Range("C1", "C500");
                pQuoteHolder = Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
                worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];

                currentFind = clients.Find(pQuoteHolder, Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                if (currentFind == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Nobody was found."); 
                }
```

So here is the problem, I see from debugging that qQuoteHolder is getting the correct value from datagridview, I can see for myself that all quote numbers in my excel sheet are indeed all in the C column and within range, so why is currentfind returning null? I am still learning excel and c#, Did I manage to code the range.Find method incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be that your quotes are numbers and you're searching with a string?

Comment: Remember `C#` arrays are 0 based while Excel is 1 based

Comment: Hi CDspace! I thought Convert.ToString would have allowed me to do this?
Hello chancea, I've tried setting "workbook.Sheets" to 0 and I get an exception thrown.